# Setup Camunda with Grails 3

Tags: spring-boot, grails, camunda

I am trying to run Camunda Community Edition with Grails 3. This is the Maven coordinate:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>camunda-bom</artifactId>
  <version>7.9.0</version>
  <scope>import</scope>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I try to translate this cordinate in gradle like this in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {    
    compile "org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bom:7.9.0"  
}
```

It compile but when I try to import camunda classes, it didn't see them. Here is my configuration

```
 Grails Version: 3.2.6
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_181
Gradle 3.0
```

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import a BOM not a simple library so try to import it as grails do. Check http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/commandLine.html to see how to do it

Comment: Thank you Jorge. I will check the link.

Answer (score 0):

Camunda doesn't support grails runtime. For supported runtime, please refer this page https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/introduction/supported-environments/